# Probability curves that approach 1

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm a game developer, but unfamiliar with mathematics or math notation.

Say I have a player who opens a chest. It might have a gold coin in it. If not, the player can come back and open it again.

I want the chance of discovering a gold coin to increase to 100% when the player opens it a specified number of times.

Here's a graph showing three curves that hit 100% on the fifth turn.

I've calculated these (where x is 1, 2 and 3) as:

> chance = turn^x / maxTurn^x

[image: Curves showing increasing probabilities up to 5 turns]

This is just fiddling with a spreadsheet - I'm not sure what I'm actually doing here. What are these curves called? I'd love to get any pointers to (introductory) information.

Comment: These are called exponential functions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth#Basic_formula

Answer (score 0):

Let C equal the percentage chance and t the turn number. Then C and t are related by the formula: $C=\frac{100t^x}{5^x}$ This is guaranteed to have a 100% chance at 5 turns, since replacing t by 5 gives $\frac{100*5^x}{5^x}=100$. Note  that you would need to design it such that after 5 turns, C=100 anyway.